# Java learning initial stage

Tags: java

I want to learn java by myself but I don't know the programming language. I am new to programming but I like to do.

So could you please guide me for learning Java

1. What software require to install it?
2. please attach the learning web site link for basics.
3. please also attach the sample examples links.

Thank You

Comment: Read the Java tag wiki for resources to get started: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info, such as [The Oracle Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: Strongly recommend BlueJ for starters. Pick yourself a good book if you like, my (subjective) favorite would be [Beginning Java Objects].


  [1]: http://www.bluej.org/
  [2]: http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Java-Objects-Concepts-Edition/dp/1590594576/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1347391367&sr=8-1&keywords=beginning%20java%20objects

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend looking at [Thinking in Java](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/). It gives you an overview of OO as well which is essential for programming well in Java. I would also look at the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) from Oracle.

As to what you might need to actually write java, I'd start with a text editor and manually compile and deploy applications. This gives you a good understanding of it. After that I'd look for an IDE such as Eclipse.